nRF52840 PCB review (2 layers)
I am currently working on a project that involves a Garmin-style devices to display acceleration and velocity data, connected in ANT. I have some background in both software and hardware development and have purchased the Nordic nRF52840 Evaluation Board.
I spent the past two weeks making the sensors work with the DK: so far so good :)
I am sensing an SPI and I2C sensors, which will be placed in a separate PCB, connected through a Molex cable. I would love to have your opinion on this schematic before I start populating my PCB.
Things to note:

for this first preproduction run of prototype PCBs, I'll be using a QFN-48 package, sinc I don't have a lot of GPIOs and I will hand solder the entire board. The QFN seems a bit more forgiving than the weird aQFN package :)

I'll be using a 2 layers PCB to save costs

this preproduction run serves to validate everything in my lab before moving to a compact, optimised solution. Hence the PCB will mostly use relatively large 0805 SMD packages and a lot of test point here and there for debug/testing purposes


I am left with some questions:

I want the USB connector to charge the battery. I have based my design on the Thingy:52 schematic. Can you confirm this is the right way to do it? Are there any specific components or configurations I should be aware of to enable this safely?

One of the difference with the Thingy layout wrt the battery is that the QFN package does not include VDHH, hence I have tied the battery voltage to VDD, is this correct?

Programming wise, everything can be done via the debug connector, can you confirm? I assume I can use the nRF52840 DK board to program my custom PCB? Do I need to power down my board while the debug cable is connected to the DK? Don't want to fry it :)

JLink: is this needed or again the nRF52840 DK is enough to perform simple flashing?

Antenna wise, I have implemented the Thingy 52 strategy, with the usage of the 2450AT18B100E antenna. Is that a good approach? Do I need to fiddle around with traces length/impedances? I have to say I know very very very little about RF design

Should I use external pull-up resistors on the I2C lines, or are they already integrated in the chip? My schematic currently has them (4.7k)

I noticed TDS protection at the USB connector in the aQFN layout. However, if the QFN does not have enough pins with USB data lines, is TVS ESD protection still recommended? Note I've added it anyways in my schematic in the form of a DT2041 chip connected to the USB D+/D-

Considering the QFN-48 Package: from looking at docs and forum posts, it seems less supported, and I’m concerned about compatibility.

All my code so far has been developed on the DK board, which has the QIAA package. Can you confirm the main difference is just HW (diff
number of GPIO, package, etc.), and that my QIAA software should work
with the QFN?


General question:

Let's say the board gets manufactured and populated correctly and it's ready to go. What would be the recommended starting or powering-up procedure to ensure everything initializes correctly? I assume I'll be using my nRF52840 DK to program/flash my custom PCB via the debug cable

Thanks so much for any guidance you can provide. I’m still in my first steps of RF design and there’s a lot to take in, so any tips or shared experiences would be really helpful.
This project is a big learning opportunity for me, and I want to make sure I’m setting everything up correctly from the start.
Appreciate any insights from the community!
Thanks again!


The image is too blurry to see necessary details. Two layers could be OK but you need to be sure, categorically impedance control is not viable on 2-layer board. An expert might be able to say if you should go directly to more layers or spend weeks getting a 2-layer board pass the official tests before noticing you really needed more to begin with. There's too many generic and individual questions that might be opinion-based, so broad review questions are not generally that great.

Please don't draw schematics like that. I know why you have drawn them like that but, it doesn't help a pro figure out the connections having to follow net names. This is why we use wires in schematics to join nodes up. There are some important exceptions of course but, your schematic doesn't have those exceptions and, as a result it's really hard to get to grips with. When you learn to read schematics better you'll understand but, for now, please take my word for it and avoid compartmentalizing trivial parts of the circuit.

"I'll be using a 2 layers PCB to save costs" No! You won't, unless this is something you have massive production volumes for. You may however fail EMC testing because of it. Proper copper pour ground planes will be so much more suitable when a RF part is present, plus it is much easier to route a fine pitch QFN if you have 4 layers.

Regarding hand-soldering of QFN48: even if you are good at it there's no guarantees. I've done my share of this using paste and hot air soldering station, still it is a gamble. So I started to hand over such jobs to an electronics assembly veteran with some 30+ years of hand soldering experience. He got about the same results as I did: on some parts we didn't get proper wetting on all pads like 1 out of 5 failing. We both eventually came to the conclusion that hand soldering such parts is simply not professional and only ever use reflow soldering since then, even for prototypes.

And yeah the aQFN or BGA will be even harder to get right without a reflow oven.

Hello guys, I've updated a new high resolution image

Please upload a image with higher resolution image of the schematic. See for example Exporting a high quality image of the schematic. If you do this, I can go through your schematic and answer your questions in more detail.
Right now, I can still answer your questions as best I can without the schematic.
2 Layers: Both the Thingy:52 and the nRF52840Dongle uses 2 layers, so it is possible to use 2 layers for the PCB. You can download schematics for these boards from Nordic Semiconductor product pages for each board, so I recommend to look at those to learn from those.

One of the difference with the Thingy layout wrt the battery is that the QFN package does not include VDHH, hence I have tied the battery voltage to VDD, is this correct?

The nRF52840 can indeed has multiple different circuit configurations. I recommend following one of the Reference Circuitries from the datasheet. As you can see there, "Circuit configuration no. 1 for QFAA QFN48" does not use VDDH either.
Furthermore, if you look at Regulator operating conditions, your input voltage must be within 1.7-3.6V with VDD, instead of 2.5-5.5V(VDDH).

Programming wise, everything can be done via the debug connector, can you confirm? I assume I can use the nRF52840 DK board to program my custom PCB? Do I need to power down my board while the debug cable is connected to the DK? Don't want to fry it :)

The nRF52840DK has an On-Board debugger, so you can connect that to SWD on the custom board to program it. The external target(your PCB) must be powered externally when programming.  See DK docs on Connectors for programming external boards for more info.

JLink: is this needed or again the nRF52840 DK is enough to perform simple flashing?

DK is enough, given that the DK voltage matches Custom PCB voltage. The DK Debugger does have a flexible voltage range, in difference from a JLink debugger.

Antenna wise, I have implemented the Thingy 52 strategy, with the usage of the 2450AT18B100E antenna. Is that a good approach? Do I need to fiddle around with traces length/impedances? I have to say I know very very very little about RF design

A chip antenna is most often used if you have limited PCB space. If you do not have size limitations, a PCB antenna is usually cheaper. For most use-cases the performance difference between a chip antenna and a PCB antenna is not significant. If you want to read more up on the details here, see for example this guide on Nordics forum DevZone which discusses Antenna design: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/guides/hardware-design-test-and-measuring/b/nrf5x/posts/general-pcb-design-guidelines-for-nrf52

Should I use external pull-up resistors on the I2C lines, or are they already integrated in the chip? My schematic currently has them (4.7k)

I used the AI function in Nordic docs (in the lower corner), and asked about this. It linked me to nRF52840 docs on TWIM — I2C compatible two-wire interface master -> Pullup resistor. And from this spec: Yes it supports internal pull-up.

All my code so far has been developed on the DK board, which has the QIAA package. Can you confirm the main difference is just HW (diff number of GPIO, package, etc.), and that my QIAA software should work with the QFN?

As long as you do not directly use any pins or functionality that the QFN does not have, the software should be the same for both package variants.

Let's say the board gets manufactured and populated correctly and it's ready to go. What would be the recommended starting or powering-up procedure to ensure everything initializes correctly? I assume I'll be using my nRF52840 DK to program/flash my custom PCB via the debug cable

Power it up and connect debugger (for example from a DK) to program.
Extra comments:
For RF Design, it is very relevant to also get a review of the PCB layout in addition to the schematic. Could you upload this as well here?
Know that Nordic Semiconductor provide free schematic and PCB reviews on their forum DevZone. If you want to have this looked at by someone who work full-time on reviewing stuff like this, you might want to check that out. If you do, make sure to mention this post in the new ticket there and vice versa.
I also work for Nordic Semiconductor, but I mostly do software, so I am doing best effort on my answers to your questions here.
I hope this was helpful.
